# effect of deleting a shared Dropbox file

Tags: dropbox

A friend has shared some concert photographs with me via Dropbox & I have them in my Dropbox folder on my iPad. She may need to delete the photos from her Dropbox to free space. Will the photos also disappear from my folder & if so is there a way I can retain copies before this is done?

Comment: Just move them to a non-shared folder

Comment: See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31457/is-it-safe-to-delete-files-from-my-dropbox-account-that-were-shared-by-someone-e

Comment: @Paul or, indeed, to one of Annjay's own Dropbox folders rather than one shared with them.

Comment: @Darael yeah, that was what I meant!

Comment: @Paul right, yes, I do apologise; I got distracted and commented on the question when I meant to comment on Xavierjazz's answer.

Answer (score 1):

To retain them, copy them to another folder on your computer.